# WebStorm unable to create Node.js Express App

Tags: javascript, node.js, intellij-idea, webstorm

I am getting the following error while trying to create a Node.js Express App:

> Error creating Node.js Express App. Cannot find C:\Users\Trunapushpa\AppData\Local\Temp\intellij-express-generator5627\node_modules\express-generator\bin\express

[image: This is the pic showing the error]

I tried creating a new Node.js express app in Windows and Linux as well, but I am getting the exact same error every time in both the operating systems.
This is the log file of WebStorm running in Windows:

```
2017-04-01 02:45:45,619 [      0]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE STARTED ------------------------------------------------------ 
2017-04-01 02:45:45,664 [     45]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - IDE: WebStorm (build #WS-163.12024.17, 31 Jan 2017 19:45) 
2017-04-01 02:45:45,664 [     45]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - OS: Windows 10 (10.0, x86) 
2017-04-01 02:45:45,664 [     45]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-408-b6 (JetBrains s.r.o) 
2017-04-01 02:45:45,664 [     45]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM: 25.112-b6 (OpenJDK Server VM) 
2017-04-01 02:45:45,666 [     47]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM Args: -Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -ea -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Djb.vmOptionsFile=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WebStorm 2016.3.3\bin\webstorm.exe.vmoptions -Xbootclasspath/a:C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WebStorm 2016.3.3\lib\boot.jar -Didea.platform.prefix=WebStorm -Didea.paths.selector=WebStorm2016.3 -XX:ErrorFile=C:\Users\Trunapushpa\java_error_in_webstorm_%p.log -XX:HeapDumpPath=C:\Users\Trunapushpa\java_error_in_webstorm.hprof 
2017-04-01 02:45:45,667 [     48]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ext: C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WebStorm 2016.3.3\jre\jre\lib\ext: [access-bridge-32.jar, access-bridge.jar, cldrdata.jar, dnsns.jar, jaccess.jar, jfxrt.jar, localedata.jar, meta-index, nashorn.jar, sunec.jar, sunjce_provider.jar, sunmscapi.jar, sunpkcs11.jar, zipfs.jar] 
2017-04-01 02:45:45,667 [     48]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNU charset: Cp1252 
2017-04-01 02:45:45,732 [    113]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNA library (32-bit) loaded in 65 ms 
2017-04-01 02:45:45,735 [    116]   INFO - penapi.util.io.win32.IdeaWin32 - Native filesystem for Windows is operational 
2017-04-01 02:45:45,736 [    117]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - Using "FocusKiller" library to prevent focus stealing. 
2017-04-01 02:45:45,746 [    127]   INFO -     #com.intellij.util.ui.JBUI - UI scale factor: 1.0 
2017-04-01 02:45:51,478 [   5859]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot find optional descriptor js-nashorn-support.xml 
2017-04-01 02:45:51,618 [   5999]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot find optional descriptor uml-properties-support.xml 
2017-04-01 02:45:51,619 [   6000]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot find optional descriptor uml-java-support.xml 
2017-04-01 02:45:52,075 [   6456]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - 55 plugins initialized in 886 ms 
2017-04-01 02:45:52,092 [   6473]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Loaded bundled plugins: ASP (0.1), AngularJS (163.12024.17), CSS Support (163.12024.17), CVS Integration (11), CoffeeScript (2.0), Cucumber.js (0.1), Dart (163.12024.17), Docker integration (2.4.1), EJS (163.12024.17), EditorConfig (163.12024.17), File Watchers (163.12024.17), Gherkin (999.999), Git Integration (8.1), GitHub (163.12024.17), HAML (163.12024.17), HTML Tools (2.0), Handlebars/Mustache (163.12024.17), IDEA CORE (163.12024.17), IntelliLang (8.0), Java Server Pages (JSP) Integration (1.0), JavaScript Debugger (1.0), JavaScript Intention Power Pack (0.9.4), JavaScript Support (1.0), Karma (163.12024.17), LESS support (163.12024.17), LiveEdit (163.12024.17), Meteor (163.12024.17), Node.js Remote Interpreter (163.12024.17), NodeJS (163.12024.17), Perforce Integration (2.0), PhoneGap/Cordova Plugin (163.12024.17), Polymer & Web Components (999.999), Pug (ex-Jade) (163.12024.17), QuirksMode (163.12024.17), REST Client (163.12024.17), Refactor-X (2.01), Remote Hosts Access (0.1), SASS support (163.12024.17), SSH Remote Run (0.1), Settings Repository (163.12024.17), Spy-js (163.12024.17), Stylus support (999.999), Subversion Integration (1.1), Task Management (1.0), Terminal (0.1), TextMate bundles support (163.12024.17), Time Tracking (1.0), UML Support (1.0), Vagrant (0.6.VERSION), W3C Validators (2.0), XPathView + XSLT Support (4), XSLT-Debugger (1.4), YAML (163.12024.17), Yeoman (163.12024.17), hg4idea (10.0) 
2017-04-01 02:45:52,770 [   7151]   INFO - ellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage - lower=100; upper=200; buffer=10; max=474 
2017-04-01 02:45:52,800 [   7181]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Starting file watcher: C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WebStorm 2016.3.3\bin\fsnotifier.exe 
2017-04-01 02:45:52,815 [   7196]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Native file watcher is operational. 
2017-04-01 02:45:52,927 [   7308]   INFO - pi.util.registry.RegistryState - Registry values changed by user: 
2017-04-01 02:45:52,927 [   7308]   INFO - pi.util.registry.RegistryState -   dumb.aware.run.configurations = true 
2017-04-01 02:45:53,884 [   8265]   INFO - rains.ide.BuiltInServerManager - built-in server started, port 63342 
2017-04-01 02:45:53,905 [   8286]   INFO - gs.impl.UpdateCheckerComponent - channel: release 
2017-04-01 02:45:54,078 [   8459]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - Index exts enumerated:65 
2017-04-01 02:45:54,085 [   8466]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - Index scheduled:7 
2017-04-01 02:45:54,109 [   8490]   INFO - tellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl - All stub exts enumerated:16 
2017-04-01 02:45:54,109 [   8490]   INFO - tellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl - stub exts update scheduled:0 
2017-04-01 02:45:54,152 [   8533]   INFO - j.ide.script.IdeStartupScripts - 0 startup script(s) found 
2017-04-01 02:45:54,273 [   8654]   INFO - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - 80 application components initialized in 3088ms 
2017-04-01 02:45:54,282 [   8663]   INFO - .intellij.idea.IdeaApplication - App initialization took 9647 ms 
2017-04-01 02:45:55,494 [   9875]   INFO - pl$FileIndexDataInitialization - Initialization done:1407 
2017-04-01 02:45:55,791 [  10172]   INFO - exImpl$StubIndexInitialization - Initialization done:297 
2017-04-01 02:45:56,472 [  10853]   INFO - .openapi.application.Preloader - Finished preloading com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionPreloader@191e350 
2017-04-01 02:45:57,381 [  11762]   INFO - .openapi.application.Preloader - Finished preloading com.intellij.ide.ui.search.SearchableOptionPreloader@13fba 
2017-04-01 02:45:57,443 [  11824]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 104 project components initialized in 2111 ms 
2017-04-01 02:45:57,519 [  11900]   INFO - le.impl.ModuleManagerComponent - 1 module(s) loaded in 65 ms 
2017-04-01 02:45:57,610 [  11991]   INFO - .openapi.application.Preloader - Finished preloading com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionPreloader@10c5456 
2017-04-01 02:45:58,072 [  12453]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Pushing properties took 109ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2017-04-01 02:45:58,279 [  12660]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Indexable file iteration took 205ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2017-04-01 02:45:58,448 [  12829]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - C:/Users/Trunapushpa/WebstormProjects/untitled1/.idea case-sensitivity: expected=false actual=false 
2017-04-01 02:45:58,582 [  12963]   INFO - tor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl - Project opening took 3660 ms 
2017-04-01 02:52:54,045 [ 428426]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 15 project components initialized in 17 ms 
2017-04-01 02:52:54,046 [ 428427]   INFO - le.impl.ModuleManagerComponent - 0 module(s) loaded in 0 ms 
2017-04-01 02:53:03,054 [ 437435]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 104 project components initialized in 33 ms 
2017-04-01 02:53:03,055 [ 437436]   INFO - le.impl.ModuleManagerComponent - 0 module(s) loaded in 0 ms 
2017-04-01 02:53:03,077 [ 437458]   INFO - i.vcs.changes.ChangeListWorker - default list not found when copy 
2017-04-01 02:53:03,077 [ 437458]   INFO - i.vcs.changes.ChangeListWorker - default list not found when copy in original object too 
2017-04-01 02:53:03,328 [ 437709]   INFO - i.vcs.changes.ChangeListWorker - default list not found when copy 
2017-04-01 02:53:03,328 [ 437709]   INFO - i.vcs.changes.ChangeListWorker - default list not found when copy in original object too 
2017-04-01 02:53:03,420 [ 437801]   INFO - Tools.base.JsbtStartupActivity - Detecting buildfiles for com.intellij.lang.javascript.buildTools.grunt.GruntfileManager 
2017-04-01 02:53:03,420 [ 437801]   INFO - Tools.base.JsbtStartupActivity - Detecting buildfiles for com.intellij.lang.javascript.buildTools.gulp.GulpfileManager 
2017-04-01 02:53:03,421 [ 437802]   INFO - Tools.base.JsbtStartupActivity - Detecting buildfiles for com.intellij.lang.javascript.buildTools.npm.PackageJsonFileManager 
2017-04-01 02:53:03,423 [ 437804]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Pushing properties took 7ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2017-04-01 02:53:03,429 [ 437810]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Indexable file iteration took 6ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2017-04-01 02:53:03,449 [ 437830]   INFO - xpress.ExpressProjectGenerator - Running '"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" install express-generator@4.15.0' in C:\Users\Trunapushpa\AppData\Local\Temp\intellij-express-generator2 
2017-04-01 02:53:06,268 [ 440649]   INFO - xpress.ExpressProjectGenerator - stdout: C:\Users\Trunapushpa\AppData\Local\Temp\intellij-express-generator2
`-- express-generator@4.15.0 
  +-- commander@2.9.0 
  | `-- graceful-readlink@1.0.1 
  +-- ejs@2.5.6 
  +-- mkdirp@0.5.1 
  | `-- minimist@0.0.8 
  `-- sorted-object@2.0.1 
2017-04-01 02:53:06,268 [ 440649]   INFO - xpress.ExpressProjectGenerator - stderr: npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Trunapushpa\AppData\Local\Temp\intellij-express-generator2\package.json'
npm WARN intellij-express-generator2 No description
npm WARN intellij-express-generator2 No repository field.
npm WARN intellij-express-generator2 No README data
npm WARN intellij-express-generator2 No license field. 
2017-04-01 02:53:06,270 [ 440651]   WARN - xpress.ExpressProjectGenerator - Cannot find C:\Users\Trunapushpa\AppData\Local\Temp\intellij-express-generator2\node_modules\express-generator\bin\express 
com.jetbrains.nodejs.boilerplate.express.ExpressProjectGenerator$GeneratorException: Cannot find C:\Users\Trunapushpa\AppData\Local\Temp\intellij-express-generator2\node_modules\express-generator\bin\express
    at com.jetbrains.nodejs.boilerplate.express.ExpressProjectGenerator.generateExpressApp(ExpressProjectGenerator.java:205)
    at com.jetbrains.nodejs.boilerplate.express.ExpressProjectGenerator.generateProject(ExpressProjectGenerator.java:86)
    at com.jetbrains.nodejs.boilerplate.express.ExpressProjectGenerator.generateProject(ExpressProjectGenerator.java:53)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.projectWizard.AbstractNewProjectStep.a(AbstractNewProjectStep.java:218)
    at com.intellij.platform.PlatformProjectOpenProcessor.doOpenProject(PlatformProjectOpenProcessor.java:234)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.projectWizard.AbstractNewProjectStep.doGenerateProject(AbstractNewProjectStep.java:222)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.projectWizard.AbstractNewProjectStep$AbstractCallback.consume(AbstractNewProjectStep.java:162)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.projectWizard.AbstractNewProjectStep$AbstractCallback.consume(AbstractNewProjectStep.java:155)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.projectWizard.ProjectSettingsStepBase$1.a(ProjectSettingsStepBase.java:131)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbPermissionServiceImpl.allowStartingDumbModeInside(DumbPermissionServiceImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbService.allowStartingDumbModeInside(DumbService.java:294)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.projectWizard.ProjectSettingsStepBase$1.actionPerformed(ProjectSettingsStepBase.java:130)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swin
```

Comment: Simple fix to this: 1) Uninstall WebStorm 2) Install VSCode 3) Profit

Comment: So... Wait for future updates! Fixed in builds
**172.1051**.
History of this issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-26270#tab=History

Answer (score 7):

The issue is caused by recent changes in express-generator structure: express.js has been renamed to express-cli.js

**To Fix**

1.npm install -g express-generator

2. express project_name
3. cd project_name, npm install
4. in webstorm, File | open, choose project_name folder

Comment: Thanks, even using a previous version of express-generator suffices.